# nodejs- mysql invalid utf8 characer string load data in file

Tags: mysql, node.js, csv, paypal, utf-8

I am writng the data returned from paypal into a csv file and then load this csv file into mysql database.

Part of data returned from Paypal : %f0%9f%98%9d%2e
Which i then decode using decodeuricomponent to ðŸ˜ .
when i save this to file and do load data in file it gives mysql error:

`Invalid utf8 character string`

The load data in file query is:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'note.csv' REPLACE INTO TABLE table1 CHARACTER SET UTF8 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (note)
```

The collation of database, table and columns is utf_general_ci

So i tried encoding the data returned from paypal using

```
utf8.encode("ðŸ˜ .")
```

And then saved it to file. But it was not encoded correctly.

After this the load data in file didn't return any error but the data saved in column was ð. Which is incorrect.

How do i correctly encode the string so that it can be loaded into the table.

Link to files:

http://speedy.sh/RMu5M/note.csv (encoded)

http://speedy.sh/ajrQj/notenonencoded.csv (nonencoded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For  (hex `f09f989d`), you need MySQL's utf8mb4, not utf8.  Use that in the table and in the connection.

Comment: The problem was I didn't knew it was an emoji. Thank you :)